# What are the sheaves in the $G$-equivariant resolutions seen as vector bundles?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, algebraic-k-theory

$\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}$
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a $G$-equivariant sheaf over a smooth projective $G$-variety $X$, generated by global sections $s_1,...s_n$.  One can construct the first locally free sheaf $\F_1$ in the resolution of $\F$.  The sheaf is $\F_1=\Gamma(X, \F)$.  It is defined as $\Gamma(X, \F)(U)=\rho_{U,X} \Gamma(X,\F)$.

(I am trying to simplify a construction given in [Ginzburg's Representation Theory and Complex Geometry page 241](https://books.google.com/books?id=OZlCAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA241#v=onepage&q&f=false))

**Since this sheaf is supposed to be locally free, what is the vector bundle over $X$ such that the sheaf of sections is $\F_1$?  In other words what is the vector bundle that corresponds to $\F_1$?**

My first guess would have been $\epsilon^n$.  This has the same global sections.  But unfortunately, it has different sections over any open.  In fact the space of sections over any open set in $X$ is going to be infinite dimensional whereas $\F_1$ has a finite dimensional (in fact with dimension less than $n$) space of sections over any open.

Answer (score 4):

If $X$ is a variety over a field $k$, then one may take ${\cal F}_1 := \Gamma(X,{\cal F}) \otimes_k {\cal O}_X$.  One gets the corresponding vector bundle from it using the standard natural construction, as in EGA, for example, and it would be isomorphic to a sum of a finite number of copies of the trivial vector bundle of rank 1.

It would be good to reserve the notation $\Gamma(X,{\cal F})$ for the $k$-vector space of global sections of $\cal F$, and to adopt a different notation for your sheaf.

Normally, the phrase *locally free sheaf* is interpreted to mean *locally free sheaf of ${\cal O}_X$-Modules*, not *locally free sheaf of $k$-modules*, which is what your definition seems to provide.  Your proposed definition, if tensored over $k$ with ${\cal O}_X$, might work, and would be a little smaller than the standard choice above when $X$ is not connected, which is perhaps what you had in mind.

Notice that on that page in the book of Ginzburg none of the tensor product symbols $\otimes$ are decorated with the ring: some are over $k$ and some are over ${\cal O}_X$; it's up to the reader to provide the correct interpretation.

If $n$ is the dimension of $\Gamma(X,{\cal F})$ over $k$, then $k^n$ is isomorphic to $\Gamma(X,{\cal F})$, but the isomorphism is not canonical, since it depends on a choice of basis, so it is best to avoid identifying the two vector spaces.

Also, be careful about identifying $\Gamma(X,{\cal O}_X)$ with $k$, since the map $k \to \Gamma(X,{\cal O}_X)$ may not be an isomorphism.

It is best to refer to *a* resolution of $\cal F$, rather than *the* resolution of $\cal F$, since there are many.